# Angular 1.5 Custom Filter for formatting different object properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am thinking how to make a custom Angular 1.5 filter which will be used for formatting the values of different object's properties. In the `html` file is rendered with `ng-repeat` this code:

```
<div>{{::object.day || object.date || 'Something else'}}</div>
```

The backend sends these object properties as they can have `null` value, so this line of code says - if the object has property `day` which has not `null` value, render it, or if the other property `date` has not `null` value, render it. If the two properties have `null` value, render `'Something else'`. 
This logic will be used on many places in the application so it's better to create a `custom Angular filter` which will hold it.
So, I made this:

```
angular.module('my-app', []).
filter('my-filter', my-filter);

function myFilter($filter){

 return function(inputDay, inputDate) {

   if(inputDay) {
     var day = $filter('date')(new Date(inputDay), 'EEE');
     return day;
   }

   else if(inputDate) {
    var date = $filter('date')(new Date(inputDate), 'M/d/yyyy');
    return date;
   }

   else {
    return 'Something else';
   }

  }

}
```

And in the `html`:

```
<div>{{::object.day | myFilter:{object:day} || object.date | myFilter:{object:date}}}</div>
```

As the last part `Something else` is not added in the expression in the html since in the filter's code it should be returned if both `inputDay` and `inputDate` are `null`.
The problem is that maybe my condition in the `html` is wrong, because the filter applies but only for the **first part** of the condition - if the object's property `day` is not `null`. So in the ng-repeated items with this property when it's not `null`, it works.
 But for the other case - when the date is not `null`, the result of the filtering is `{}`. The same for the third case when `day` and `date` have `null` values, instead of `Something else`, it displays `{}`.
After some debugging I saw that the property of the object is `undefined`.

```
Object {myobject: undefined}
```

Where is my mistake? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution.

This is the template:

```
<div id="body">
  <div ng-controller="FrameController as vm">
    <div>{{vm.firstObject.day && (vm.firstObject.day|myFilter:'day') || vm.firstObject.date && (vm.firstObject.date|myFilter:'date')}}</div>
    <div>{{vm.secondObject.day && (vm.secondObject.day|myFilter:'day') || vm.secondObject.date && (vm.secondObject.date|myFilter:'date')}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the JavaScript part:

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('myFilter', function ($filter){

return function(inputDate, formatType) {
if(formatType === 'day') {
     var day = $filter('date')(new Date(inputDate), 'EEE');
     return day;
   }
   else if(formatType === 'date') {
    var date = $filter('date')(new Date(inputDate), 'M/d/yyyy');
    return date;
   }

   return 'Something else';
}
})
.controller('FrameController', ['$injector', function($injector) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.message = 'Hello world';
  vm.firstObject = {
     day: new Date()
  };
  vm.secondObject = {
     date: new Date()
  };
}]);

setTimeout(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ['app']);
});
```

and here is the working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2mbs3o4s/

Comment: Thanks for the help!